# Converting an object to a Stack type

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to take the object i am getting, stackVal, and convert it to a object type Stack and this is my code but it is not working and im not sure of any other way. If anyone could help out please it would be appreciated!

---

```
      object stackVal;
      Stack<Event> eventStack = new Stack<Event>();
      CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

            if (phoneAppSer.State.ContainsKey("STACK"))
            {
                if (phoneAppSer.State.TryGetValue("STACK", out stackVal))
                {

                 eventStack = Convert.ChangeType(stackVal, typeof(EventStack),provider);

                }
            }
```

Comment: What is State? I'm going to assume it's a Dictionary<String, X>. If X *is originally* an *Event* (could you please post the code for your Event class), then you should be able to cast the object `stackVal` to an Event (since it was originally an event). If whatever you're getting out of that `State` dictionary *is not originally* an Event, then you have to create a `new Event()` and manually and selectively transfer information from the `stackVal` object to the Event. You have to know *what* `stackVal` is to do this in the first place, though.

Comment: How do you know `it is not working`? Do you get an exception? If so, what are the details?

Comment: this is the error i am getting 

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack<BallStats.Event>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

StackEvent and the generic type Stack are not the same type. You are trying to assign the response from Convert which is of type EventStack to a variable of type Stack. The compiler is hinting that you should do:

```
eventStack = (Stack<Event>) Convert.ChangeType(stackVal, typeof(EventStack),provider);
```